# How to mock a wrapped Microsoft ASP.NET Core Client SignalR HubConnection class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-signalr

I am in the process of implementing my first signalR application and have hit a stumbling block with respect to testing. I am using `Moq` framework.

Unfortunately, I am finding that Microsoft's [HubConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnection?view=aspnetcore-3.0) class is not easily mockable using `Moq` framework, i.e. it does not have virtual methods and does not directly implement an interface. Microsoft's official [suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8133) is for developers to implement a wrapper class and interface, which I have done, see small sample of class `HubProxy` below. The problem that I am now encountering is how to test the wrapped `HubConnection` class is triggered by the wrapper?

I have initially derived a class from HubConnection, `MockedHubConnection` below that uses `new` to try and override. The `MockedHubConnection` methods throw a `NotImplementedException`. In the test below, it asserts that NotImplementedException is thrown to signify that the wrapped HubConnection has been triggered. However, I am receiving a NullReference exception from the test:

```sh
Actual:   typeof(System.NullReferenceException): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
---- System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Stack Trace:
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.BeginScope[TState](TState state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.BeginScope[TState](TState state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I think what is happening, is that the the constructor of `HubProxy` class is implictly converting the mock HubConnection to the real `HubConnection` instance??

How is it possible to test a wrapper class that wraps a third party class which does not provide a mockable interface or virtual methods that can be overriden?

**Hub Proxy Sample - Wraps HubConnection**

```
public class HubProxy : IHubProxy
{
    private readonly HubConnection connection;
    
    public HubProxy(HubConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancel=default)
    {
        this.connection.StopAsync(cancel);
    }
}
```

**Mock HubConnection - throws NotImplementedException to test invoked by wrapper**

```
 public class MockHubConnection : HubConnection
    {
        public MockHubConnection(
            IConnectionFactory connection,
            IHubProtocol protocol,
            EndPoint endPoint,
            IServiceProvider provider,
            ILoggerFactory factory,
            IRetryPolicy policy
        ) : base(connection, protocol, endPoint, provider, factory, policy) { }

        public new Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Mock HubConnection - Initial Attempt - Using new to override**

```
    public class MockHubConnection : HubConnection
    {
        public MockHubConnection(
            IConnectionFactory connection,
            IHubProtocol protocol,
            EndPoint endPoint,
            IServiceProvider provider,
            ILoggerFactory factory,
            IRetryPolicy policy
        ) : base(connection, protocol, endPoint, provider, factory, policy) { }

        public new Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Test Sample**

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task HubProxy_StopAsync_Invokes_HubConnection_StopAsync()
        {
            var mockCon = Mock.Of<IConnectionFactory>();
            var mockHubProtocol = Mock.Of<IHubProtocol>();
            var mockServiceProvider = Mock.Of<IServiceProvider>();
            var mockLoggerFactory = Mock.Of<ILoggerFactory>();
            var mockRetryPolicy = Mock.Of<IRetryPolicy>();

            var mockHubConnection = new MockHubConnection(
                mockCon,
                mockHubProtocol,
                new IPEndPoint(0, 0),
                mockServiceProvider,
                mockLoggerFactory,
                mockRetryPolicy
            );

            var _client = new HubProxy(mockHubConnection);

            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<NotImplementedException>(() => _client.StopAsync());
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea behind creating a wrapper class is to mock the wrapper class.  The wrapper class would act only as a pass through to the actual class you're trying to use, so it would not have any logic of it's own.  Since you are using MOQ you need not create a mock class for the `HubConnection`.  You would mock `IHubProxy` so you don't use anything related to `HubConnection`.

```
var mockHubProxy = new Mock<IHubProxy>();

// Since you're only trying find out if a 
// method is called then you would use MOQ's verify method.
mockHubProxy.Verify(x => x.StopAsync());

// If you really want an exception to be thrown then you 
// would do the following.  Though I don't think this is the way to go.
mockHubProxy.Setup(x => x.StopAsync()).Throws(new NotImplementedException());
```

Does this make sense?  Notice there is nothing here about `HubConnection`.  The whole point of the wrapper, `HubProxy`, is to remove anything related to `HubConnection` since it can't be tested.  In your actual implementation of `HubProxy` your `StopAsync` method would call the concrete implementation of `HubConnection.StopAsync()`.  In your mock it does nothing.  It just make sure that it's called.

I don't know the methods of the `HubConnection` so I'm just going to use made up method names in the example below of how to implement the wrapper for methods that actually have return values.

```
public interface IHubProxy
{
    string GetStringValue();
}


public HubProxy: IHubProxy 
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public HubProxy()
    {
        _connection = new HubConnection();
    }

    public string GetStringValue() 
    {
        return _connection.GetStringValue();
    }
}
```

Your mock for this would then look like this

```
var mockHubProxy = new Mock<IHubProxy>();
mockHubProxy.Setup(x => x.GetStringValue()).Returns("expected string value")
```

Comment: Thanks @dogyear. Yes, thanks, that part makes sense. Does that mean I do not write tests for the hubproxy itself, i.e. tests that check that the proxy passes through to the actual class? What about code coverage of the hub proxy?

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp you write tests for the proxy, not the actual class.  I've added another example.  What you're interested in testing is the return results, so you would mock your HubProxy to return results that you are testing for.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand thanks :) By doing the mock of the proxy the coverage still gets hit, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "coverage still gets hit", but because proxy is just a pass through (literally a proxy for the actual HubConnection), you are essentially mocking HubConnection.  So any test needing to mock HubConnection can mock IHubProxy instead.

Comment: Ok accepting answer. By "coverage still gets hit", I mean does test code coverage get registered for the lines of code within the proxy?

Comment: Thank you!  And no, i don't believe it'll hit that code.  You'll most likely need to write an integration test for the concrete implementation of HubProxy that will use the actual HubConnection to get test coverage for HubProxy.  What the interface IHubProxy does for unit testing is just allow the consumer of the interface to use the "values" being returned from it because you're providing your tests with your own implementation of IHubProxy (the mock) and not the actual implementation of IHubProxy (being HubProxy).

Comment: Ok, many thanks :) Understand it now. Thanks again for your help @doyear, much appreciated :)

Comment: That being said, I typically don't bother writing any unit or integration tests for pass through wrapper classes because they don't contain any logic to test for.  I generally treat them no different than third party classes that I consumed from a source I have no control over.  Other's might have a different opinion and I'm interested in what others have to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225119/discussion-between-dogyear-and-anon-dcs3spp).