# ASP.NET Core SignalR Mocking HubConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

Is the usage of a Wrapper (e.g. IHubProxy) still the best way to mock the SignalR HubConnection for Unit Tests? (I am not really enthusiastic about this solution as it means more maintenance.)

Here is an example of IHubProxy (I don't like this solution):
See: [How to mock a wrapped Microsoft ASP.NET Core Client SignalR HubConnection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009412/how-to-mock-a-wrapped-microsoft-asp-net-core-client-signalr-hubconnection-class/77263315#77263315)